# Product construction for given two finite automata

Tags: finite-automata, nondeterminism

I need to construct a finite automata which accept a language $L =  L_1 \cap L_2$, where $L_1$ and $L_2$ are given below.

$L_1 = \{  w \mid w $ is divisible by 2 }

$L_1 = \{ w  \mid w $ is divisible by 3 }

I know how to design a finite automata for a single number but how do I combine the automatons which check divisibility by 2 and 3? I am able to combine the initial states of the two automatons by using ϵ transitions from a new state but how can I combine the final states of the two automatons? Input is in the set of decimal numbers
 Σ = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

Comment: I think you need to read the product construction. https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs373/sp2010/lectures/lect_04.pdf

Comment: Please edit your question so it makes sense without people needing to read the comments. Also, what does it mean for the input to be divisible by a number? There are multiple ways in which the input could be considered to be a number, so you need to say which one applies.

Comment: You're aware, I hope, that this problem doesn't actually need the product construction: just check for divisibility by 6.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a product construction for finite automata. I am considering you have two finite automata $M_1$ and $M_2$.

Let $M_1$ = $(Q_1,\Sigma ,\delta_1,q_{01},F_1)$ and $M_2$ = $(Q_2,\Sigma ,\delta_2,q_{02},F_2)$ be two finite automata with the same input alphabet.
Let us define $M$ such that

> $$L(M) = L(M_1) \cap L(M_2) $$

Finite automata for $L(M)$ is defined as $M$ = $(Q,\Sigma ,\delta,q_0,F)$ , where
$Q$ is a finite set of states, $\Sigma$ is a input alphabet, $q_0$ is a start state, $\delta$ is a transition function and $F$ is final state of a finite automata $M$.

> - $Q$ = $Q_1$ X $Q_2$ (Cartesian product),
> - $\delta((q_1,q_2),a) = (\delta_1(q_1,a),\delta_2(q_2,a))$,
> - $q_0 = (q_{01},q_{02})$,
> - $(q_{1},q_{2}) \in F $ iff $q_1 \in F_1 $ and $q_2 \in F_2$.

Each state in $Q$ is a pair consisting of a state from $Q_1$ and a state from $Q_2$.

**Reference** : [the Product Construction for Automata](https://web.archive.org/web/20170829080943/https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/lkovacs/ATCSNotes/atcs_h2.pdf) by Laura Kovács.

Comment: can you explain it with a small example?