# Intersection of two DFA's

Tags: finite-automata

I am trying to understand the intersection of 2 DFA's. I got the following link:
[Intersection of 2 DFAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780521/how-to-use-the-intersection-construction-to-form-a-dfa)
I can't understand why they have not used the symbol 'b'. In the DFA's they have symbol 'b' also but they are just talking about symbol 'a'.

> For M', we have...
>
> 1.E' = {a}
>
> 2.Q' = {s0, s1}
>
> 3.q0' = s0
>
> 4.A' = {s0}
>
> 5.f'(s0, a) = s1, f'(s1, a) = s0

For example in line (1) they have just symbol 'a'. However, the DFA uses both 'a' and 'b'.

Similarly:

> For M'', we have...
>
> 1.E'' = {a}
>
> 2.Q'' = {t0, t1, t2}
>
> 3.q0'' = t0
>
> 4.A'' = {t0}
>
> 5.f''(t0, a) = t1, f''(t1, a) = t2, f''(t2, a) = t0

there is no 'b' transition.
Does it mean that we would consider them one by one. For example, we can write (5) above for 'b' also  like:

f''(t0,a) =..

Also I want to know if the states in Machine 1 is not equal to states in Machine2 , what will we do?

Some body please guide me.

Zulfi.

Comment: https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs373/sp2010/lectures/lect_04.pdf, https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/71365/755

Comment: Somebody please provide me an example.

Comment: The first link I provided already has an example.

Comment: Okay I found the example, but I am trying to understand it.